# How to change state of button on click and revert back to the original state when clicked again in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, use-state

I have a button which I have defined as:

```
<button className={class} onClick={() => changeClassProperty()}>
        {classText}
</button>
```

I want to change the css styling class and the text of the button **A** onclick. So currently I am doing this using UseState hoook as follows:

```
const [classColor, setClassColor] = useState(styles.classAButton);
const [classText, setClassText] = useState("A");
```

The changeClassColor() handler is reponsible for changing the css color style and the text of my button as:

```
function changeClassProperty() {
    setClassColor(styles.classBButton);
    setClassText("B");
  }
```

So on the click of button **A** it changes it color and text to my button **B**. Now, I want that whenever a click is made to the button it switches between the states A and B. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the previous state using arrow function in `setState`

```
setClassText(prev => prev === "A" ? "B" : "A");
```